# Why do gray lines appear around the paths?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am starting to make a visualization in d3 that colors each zip code differently. Here it is so far. Sorry about how it takes ~10 seconds to load:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1531353/Misc/why_gray_lines_in_d3/index.html

Here's the javascript:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

    var path = d3.geo.path();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "zips_us_topo.json")
    .await(ready);

    function ready(error, us) {
      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.zip_codes_for_the_usa).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "zip")
      .attr("data-zip", function(d) {return d.properties.zip; })
      .attr("d", path);
    }
```

I am trying to make the gray lines around zip code regions disappear. I've tried

```
.zip {stroke-width: 0}
```

to no avail. Where do the gray lines come from? They aren't the `fill` of the paths since I set the fill to be black, not gray.

Comment: It looks like something else is being drawn that causes the gray lines. Could you reduce it to a smaller example please? I'm finding it extremely difficult to debug this as there are so many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `stroke:rgb(0,0,0);` 
Also, rather than stroke-width:0, its best to use stroke:none;